# Using the setuid bit in Linux

Tags: c, linux, unix, setuid

I have this `C` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", getlogin());
    printf("%i\n", getuid());
}
```

I compile it, set the UID and GID both to `root` and set the setuid bit, so that it looks like this:

```
-rwsrwsr-x 1 root    root    8735 Apr  8 19:51 a.out
```

However when I call `$ ./a.out` I still get:

```
user
1000
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *real user ID* is still the user that called the program, but the *effective user ID* is root.  In a setuid program, they are not the same.

To get the effective user ID, call `geteuid()`.  You can also use `cuserid()` to get the name associated with the effective user ID.

Comment: How can I get the name of the EUID?

Answer (score 1):

Your program has got only the permission to change its uid. To actually switch to  root you have to call `setuid(0)` in it.
Please have a look [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setuid)